# Where can I find descriptions of arXiv categories?

Tags: arxiv

I've recently gone through the arXiv categories (quite randomly) and found a couple where I'm not too sure what they are about. Is anywhere a description of the categories?

For **example**, I'm not too sure what the following are about / what I should expect to be in them:

- [Learning](http://arxiv.org/list/cs.LG/recent)
- [Computers and Society](http://arxiv.org/list/cs.CY/recent)

Comment: Most of them are self-explanatory... Which one does sound vague for you?

Comment: The ones I've stated in my question as examples.

Comment: `Learning` category just cover the machine learning and all related topics to artificial learning systems in the realm of theoretical CS... And `Computer  and Society` type has been defined to represent the research works about the utilization of the computer systems within the social life and humanity... For a person familiar with the CS topics, such titles might not be vague, noticeably.

Comment: @Matinking I am a Computer Science student in the end of my masters degree with specialization in machine learning. Still "learning" as a category seems pretty vague to me. It could be (1) machine learning (2) learning in the sense of instructing people how to use computers (3) some kind of playground where you can submit papers just to try out arxiv (4) studying (to understand) the process of human learning (5) something I can't think of because I'm not familiar with.

Comment: You need to interpret the title with due attention to the applied hierarchical manner... As the parent family for this title is `CS`, you should just concentrate on the related definitions to `CS` to the target title. With such view point, the compilation would be easier and more comprehensible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the arxiv.org home page, click on *detailed description* for the discipline that you need (everything except physics has one). For instance, the one for [computer science](http://arxiv.org/corr/subjectclasses) reads:

> LG - Machine Learning [...]
>
> Covers machine learning and computational (PAC) learning. Roughly includes material in ACM Subject Class I.2.6.
>
> CY - Computers and Society [...]
>
> Covers impact of computers on society, computer ethics, information technology and public policy, legal aspects of computing, computers and education. Roughly includes material in ACM Subject Classes K.0, K.2, K.3, K.4, K.5, and K.7.

Comment: The "detailed information"-page for Mathematics does also not contain any further information on the subject classes. But explanations are [here](https://arxiv.org/archive/math) (when you click on Mathematics directly.